# Django Model Choice Field: Huge List of choices

Tags: django, django-forms

Consider these 3 models:

```
# models.py
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Institute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    roll = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    institute = models.ForeignKey(Institute)
```

Now I am creating a model form to add/edit students but I provide the option to select city and institute to the user.  So basically when a user selects city the corresponding institutes are displayed using JavaScript

```
# forms.py
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city = forms.ModelChoiceField(City)
    institute = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Institute.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = Student
```

But the number of institutes is over 3000. So what I want is to keep the choices as blank initially for institute field (coz they will be filled by the JavaScript once the user selects a City), but upon submitting the data, I get a "Select a valid choice" validation error. Any ideas how to tackle such problem?

Note: When I do NOT specify choices (for institute field) the web page size is 300KB and when I specify them the size of web page is 1.1MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, I had to override the Choice widget and change its render method to display no options. Since choices argument is still provided, the validation error does not occur and I can freely use javascript to render institutes by the city selected.

Comment: I encountered exactly the same problem. To solve this, you should simply set your institute field's choices to an empty list. soyacz's answer is the right way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but overcomed it by setting widget.choices to []

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city = forms.ModelChoiceField(City)
    institute = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Institute.objects.all())

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(StudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['institute'].widget.choices = []
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that the `Institute` values that get filled up in the select box should also have the primary key as the html `id` attribute.